# Is there any freeware to develop the XMPP Gateway ?

Tags: soap, xmpp

I am trying to develop the XMPP Gateway which can send/receive from standard XMPP client. This XMPP Gateway should support conversion of XMPP request to Soap and vice-versa. Server which i am trying to integrate support only soap. 
I don't want to develop XMPP Gateway from scratch. I have seen Axis Vysper but could not found how to tweak this according to my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Vysper can be used to do that. Even though Vysper has no built-in support for SOAP (like the standard XMPP extension http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0072.html), you can create your own module to capture XMPP messages and issue SOAP calls, just like in a web app you are creating your own Servlets to intercept HTTP request and issue database calls.

One example of how to create a Module and related stuff you can find under

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mina/vysper/trunk/server/core/src/test/java/org/apache/vysper/xmpp/modules/extension/xep0054_vcardtemp